# Como identificar permutações em colunas de matrizes em C++

Tags: python, c++

Na faculdade, preciso fazer um exercício --- o enunciado está baixo --- em que eles testam com matrizes de diferentes dimensões, ou seja, preciso fazer um programa que lê matriz e escreve a matriz que o programa de teste dá input. Fiz um código em python, mas não consegui traduzir ele para C++.

Segue o código que lê e escreve em python:

```
    quantidade_linhas = 0
def ler_matriz():
    m = []
    ler_linha = input()
    global quantidade_linhas
    while ler_linha:
        m.append([int(i) for i in ler_linha.split(' ') if i])
        ler_linha = input()
        quantidade_linhas += 1
    return m
```

Segue o que tentei fazer em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > leiaMatriz(int L, int C) {
  vector<vector<int> > m;
  for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    vector<int> v1;
    for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
      int aux;
      cin >> aux;
      v1.push_back(aux); 
    }
    m.push_back(v1); 
  }  
  return m;
}
void escrevaMatriz(vector<vector<int> > m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m[0].size(); j++) {
       cout << m[i][j] << "\t ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Também vou deixar um exemplo de exercicio que pedem essa singularidade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Poderiam me dar uma luz?

Comment: Não entendi como seu programa, em Python ou C++, vai na direção de dar a resposta esperada. Precisa ler a tal "matriz" e dizer se as colunas pares são permutações. Pode usar um loop para verificar isso, nem precisa de um container: vai usar uma coluna como referência e comparar com as outras (pares) para ver se são simples permutações e pode parar na primeira diferença encontrada

Answer (score 0):

C++ e C não tem essa noção de matrizes como em FORTRAN. Existe apenas vetor, e uma matriz é um vetor de vetor, ou um vetor de vetor de vetor e assim por diante. No seu caso ousou por exemplo `vector<vector<int>>`

Uma matriz é apenas um endereço, dado pelo nome, e as dimensões. Note que pode escrever

```
    using Matriz = vector<vector<int>>;
    vector<vector<int>> teste;
    Matriz outra;
```

e teste e outra serão vetores de vetores de `int`

**De volta ao programa**

Para saber se os elementos de um vetor são ou não permutação dos valores de outro vetor em geral se usa um vetor de bits, com um bit para cada elemento,para marcar os elementos que já encontrou, e num loop procura todos elementos do vetor original. E vai marcando no vetor de bits, já que podem ter valores repetidos, como no caso de seu exemplo. Se encontrar todos então tem claro uma permutação.

Como no seu caso os valores já estão em uma matriz lida pode não fazer sentido extrair os vetores correspondentes às colunas pares para ver depois se são todas permutações, como pede o enunciado.

C++ aloca vetores por linha, então considerando sua matriz de exemplo

```
    int const M[6][4] =
    {
        { 8, 3, 7, 1 },
        { 5, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 7, 1, 6, 1 },
        { 8, 6, 8, 7 },
        { 6, 7, 6, 1 },
        { 6, 1, 5, 1 }
    };
```

esses valores vão estar na memória assim

```
         8, 3, 7, 1, 5, 8, 8, 8, 7, 1, 6, 1, ...
```

Assim os elementos de uma certa coluna ficam a uma distância fixa um do outro, e essa distância é o número de colunas. E os elementos de uma linha ficam alinhados um depois do outro.

Pode ser vantagem então usar a matriz simplesmente como `int*` e passar as dimensões para uma função que verifique a permutação **sem** extrair as colunas, **sem** criar o vetor de bits e **sem** mexer na matriz original para marcar os elementos encontrados. Algo como

```
int cpp_matriz (const int A, const int B, int* const M, int l, int c);
```

Onde

- `A` e `B` são as colunas,
- `M` é a matriz
- `l` e `c` são as dimensões

e que retorna 1 se A e B são permutações dos mesmos elementos

Vou mostrar um exemplo em C++, que compila em C também, e que faz isso. Não há muita vantagem em usar `vector` ou classes para um caso desses, já que é apenas manipulação de memória.

### Um exemplo em C++

Esse exemplo compila em C também. Não achei relevante a diferença aqui porque a idéia é a mesma. E não vi vantagem em usar STL.

#### Saída do exemplo

```
        matriz exemplo 6x4

        8    3    7    1
        5    8    8    8
        7    1    6    1
        8    6    8    7
        6    7    6    1
        6    1    5    1

original    8    5    7    8    6    6
alvo        8    5    7    8    6    6
colunas (0,0) = permutacao

original    8    5    7    8    6    6
alvo        3    8    1    6    7    1
colunas (1,0) = NAO permutacao

original    8    5    7    8    6    6
alvo        7    8    6    8    6    5
colunas (2,0) = permutacao

original    8    5    7    8    6    6
alvo        1    8    1    7    1    1
colunas (3,0) = NAO permutacao
```

#### o algoritmo

O programa apenas replica o que se faria com papel e caneta. comparando os valores das colunas A e B usando um vetor de índices que mostra os elementos ainda não usados na outra coluna, e usa esse vetor para orientar as comparações. Ao final ele deve estar vazio.

Eis o código relevante

```
int cpp_matriz(const int A, const int B, int* const M, int l, int c)
{
    // prepara ix[], vetor de indices
    int* ix = (int*)malloc( (1 + l) * sizeof(int) );
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 1) ix[1 + i] = i;
    ix[0] = l;
    // procura todos de A em B
    for (int li = 0, fim = l*c; li < fim; li += c)
    {   // usa so os que sobraram de B, que estao em ix[]
        for (int j = 1; j <= ix[0]; j += 1)
        {
            if ( *(M + A + li) == *(M + B + ix[j] * c))
            {   // achou esse
                // se nao for o ultimo inverte
                if (j != ix[0]) ix[j] = ix[ix[0]];
                ix[0] -= 1; // um a menos
                break;       // esse tinha
            };  // if()
        }; // for(j)
    }; // for(li)
    int res = (ix[0] == 0);  // se nao sobrou = permutacao
    free(ix);
    return res;
};  // cpp_matriz()
```

#### O resumo do resumo

```
            if ( *(M + A + li) == *(M + B + ix[j] * c))
```

Essa é a comparação que resolve o problema. `A` e `B` são as coluna e `M` a matriz com `li` linhas e `c` colunas. E o vetor `ix` traz os elementos ainda não usados

#### O código completo

````
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int cpp_matriz (const int A, const int B, int* const M, int l, int c);
int mostra_coluna(int const coluna, int* const M, int l, int c, const char* tit);
int mostra_matriz(
    int* const M, int const l, int const, char const* tit);


int main(void)
{
    int       res     = 0;
    int const M[6][4] =
    {
        { 8, 3, 7, 1 },
        { 5, 8, 8, 8 },
        { 7, 1, 6, 1 },
        { 8, 6, 8, 7 },
        { 6, 7, 6, 1 },
        { 6, 1, 5, 1 }
    };  //  permutacao exemplo

    mostra_matriz((int* const)M, 6, 4, "\n\tmatriz exemplo 6x4\n");
    int base = 0;  // compara com todas as outras
    for (int alvo = 0; alvo < 4; alvo += 1)
    {
        mostra_coluna(base, (int* const)M, 6, 4, "\noriginal");
        mostra_coluna(alvo, (int* const)M, 6, 4, "alvo    ");
        res = cpp_matriz(base, alvo, (int* const)M, 6, 4);
        if (res)
            printf("colunas (%d,%d) = permutacao\n", alvo, base);
        else
            printf("colunas (%d,%d) = NAO permutacao\n", alvo, base);
    };  // for()
    return 0;
}


// retorna 1 se colunas A e B em M[l][c] forem permutacoes
int cpp_matriz(const int A, const int B, int* const M, int l, int c)
{
    // prepara ix[], vetor de indices
    int* ix = (int*)malloc( (1 + l) * sizeof(int) );
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 1) ix[1 + i] = i;
    ix[0] = l;
    // procura todos de A em B
    for (int li = 0, fim = l*c; li < fim; li += c)
    {   // usa so os que sobraram de B, que estao em ix[]
        for (int j = 1; j <= ix[0]; j += 1)
        {
            if ( *(M + A + li) == *(M + B + ix[j] * c))
            {   // achou esse
                // se nao for o ultimo inverte
                if (j != ix[0]) ix[j] = ix[ix[0]];
                ix[0] -= 1; // um a menos
                break;       // esse tinha
            };  // if()
        }; // for(j)
    }; // for(li)
    int res = (ix[0] == 0);  // se nao sobrou = permutacao
    free(ix);
    return res;
};  // cpp_matriz()


int mostra_coluna(
    int const coluna, int* const M, int l, int c, const char* tit)
{  // mostra a coluna 'coluna'
    if (tit != NULL)
        printf("%s", tit);
    else
        printf("coluna %d: ", coluna);
    for (int j = 0, fim = l * c; j < fim; j += c)
        printf("%5d", *(M + coluna + j));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


int mostra_matriz(int* const M, int l, int c, char const* tit)
{
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 1)
    {
        printf("    "); // margem esquerda
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j += 1)
        {
            printf("%5d", *(M + (c * i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
/*
https//pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/519189/
como-fazer-um-m%c3%a9todo-de-leitura-e-escrita-de-matriz-em-c
*/```
````